# Laravel 5 How to validate atleast 1 checkbox

Tags: php, checkbox, laravel-5

I need to check if at least 1 checkbox is checked, I'm new in laravel so I don't know how will I do it with a checkbox, already tried it with a text field only but in a checkbox I don't know if `'required'=>'required'` will work.

This is my code

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="border: 1px solid;border-color:#ddd">
    <h5 style="color : #4897D3;">Services Quote for:</h5>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="quote[]" value="CON"> CON - Consulting
                 </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="quote[]" value="SMM"> SMM - Social Media Marketing
                 </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="quote[]" value="EVT"> EVT - Virtual Tour New
                 </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

can anyone help me or suggest on how will i do it?

Answer (score 0):

try to using validator:

```
Validator::make( 
[ 'quote' => Input::get('quote') ],
[ 'quote' => 'min:1' ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
if (!empty($request->quote)) {
    // Code to run IF checkboxes are checked
}
```

That way you could extract checked boxes inside the condition via array manipulation (since `$request->quote` is an array).

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand the concept:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="quote[]" />
```

here you are making more than one checkbox with the name `quote`, the name itself is an array so that it can accept multiple values in it.

Now at controller side put a check like:

```
if(isset($request->quote) && count($request->quote) == 0)
{
    // No checkbox is checked
}

if(isset($request->quote) && count($request->quote) == 1)
{
    // 1 checkbox is checked
}
```

Comment: in my controller i put this, $quote = implode(",", Input::get('quote', [])); How will i do it with your code? Sorry still newbie.

Comment: What you are trying to do this with code? 
I can tell you some easy for that

Comment: this code store all the values that were checked in the checkbox in $quote in a single column in database. what do you suggest on how to do it? i just want to validate that they need to check atleast 1 checkbox before they can submit the form.

Comment: Try this : $quote = implode(",", Input::get('quote');

Answer (score 0):

In laravel you can write validation rules in your request file.

Example: app\Http\Requests\MyFormRequest.php

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Requests;

    use App\Http\Requests\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
    use Response;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

 class MyFormRequest extends Request {

/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{

    return [
     'quote' => 'min:1' 
   ];

    }
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'quote' => 'Select minimum 1 checkbox'
    ];
}

}
```

LeadinfoController.php

```
 <?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use App\Http\Requests\MyFormRequest;

         ......
         ......

  class LeadinfoController extends Controller {

       ......
         ........

       public function multiple_upload(MyFormRequest $request) { 
              $form_data= $request->all();
              .........
              .........
       }

      .........
      .........

}
```

Refer : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#form-request-validation

Comment: tried  copying the code in my request.php but it still dont validate the checkbox. it sitll submit the form even without checking atleast one checkbox.

Comment: please don't copy the code as it is. You have to refer the tutorial and write new one @Ace

Comment: inorder to apply this request/validation, you have to write your controller function like :     public function myfunction(MyFormRequest $request){  $form_data= $request->all();  }

Comment: public function multiple_upload() { 
$quote = implode(",", Input::get('quote', []));
$userId = Auth::user()->id;
$user = new leadinfo;
$user->quote = $quote;
$user->save();
Session::flash('success', 'Upload successfully'); 
return Redirect::to('home');

Comment: controller name? @Ace

Comment: Oh sorry. LeadinfoController.php is the name of the controller. Sorry for the late reply, trying something if it will work but still no luck, still cant validate it.